# Map not received when using nav2d with gazebo

Tags: gazebo, navigation, rviz, gmapping, nav2d-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use nav2d to autonomously map out an environment in gazebo but I am unable to get the gmapping nav2d node "mapper" to publish a /map msg.  First I launch the turtlebot_gazebo/turtlebot_world.launch to start the turtlebot in gazebo and then I launch a modified version of the nav2d tutorial3.launch file.

In RVIZ, I get an error message under the map section that says "no map received" and "No transform [] to [map].  The output of rostopic echo /map is "WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.Is /clock being published?"  I checked /clock and it is publishing so that is not the issue.

Also, when I run turtlebot_gazebo/gmapping_demo instead of nav2d, a /map msg is published correctly so I don't think its an issue with my gazebo configuration.  My guess is that the nav2d "mapper" node is connected to the wrong laser frame but I have tried changing the base frame from base_laser_link to base_laser and to camera_depth_frame and neither worked.

Rqt_graph shows a /scan msg being published to mapper and a /map msg being published to RVIZ.

Below are my launch file and ros.yaml file which defines the parameters for nav2d.

Here is my current launch file:

```
 <launch>

    <!-- Some general parameters -->
    <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/ros.yaml"/>

    <!-- Start Stage simulator with a given environment -->
    <!--<node name="Stage" pkg="stage_ros" type="stageros" args="$(find nav2d_t$
            <param name="base_watchdog_timeout" value="0" />
    </node>
 -->
    <!-- Start the Operator to control the simulated robot -->
    <node name="Operator" pkg="nav2d_operator" type="operator" >
    <!--    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/> -->
            <remap from="cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" />
            <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/operator.yaml"/>
            <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/costmap.yaml" ns="loc$
    </node>

    <!-- Start Mapper to genreate map from laser scans -->
    <node name="Mapper" pkg="nav2d_karto" type="mapper">
                <!--<remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>-->
            <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/mapper.yaml"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Start the Navigator to move the robot autonomously -->
    <node name="Navigator" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="navigator">
            <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/navigator.yaml"/>
    </node>

    <node name="GetMap" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="get_map_client" />
    <node name="Explore" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="explore_client" />
    <node name="SetGoal" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="set_goal_client" />
  <!-- Start the joystick-driver and remote-controller for operation-->
  <!--    <node name="Joystick" pkg="joy" type="joy_node" />
    <node name="Remote" pkg="nav2d_remote" type="remote_joy" />
   -->
    <!-- Pioneer model for fancy visualization -->
    <!-- Comment this out if you do not have the package 'p2os' available! -->
   <!--    <include file="$(find p2os_urdf)/launch/pioneer3at_urdf.launch" />
    <node name="front_left_wheel" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" ar$
    <node name="front_right_wheel" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" a$
    <node name="back_left_wheel" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" arg$
    <node name="back_right_wheel" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" ar$
  -->
    <!-- RVIZ to view the visualization -->
    <node name="RVIZ" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args=" -d $(find nav2d_tutorials)/$

   </launch>
```

ros.yaml file:

```
   ###########################################################
   # Defines topics services and frames for all modules

   ### TF frames #############################################
   laser_frame: base_laser_link
   robot_frame: base_link
   odometry_frame: odom
   offset_frame: offset
   map_frame: map

   ### ROS topics ############################################
   map_topic: map
   laser_topic: scan ## ORIG = base_scan

   ### ROS services ##########################################
   map_service: static_map
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229676/map-not-received-when-using-nav2d-with-gazebo/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ankur74](https://answers.ros.org/users/26690/ankur74/) on 2016-04-24**:
Were you able to resolve this issue, I am facing the same problem with my turtlebot.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-04-26**:
Can you post the output from rqt_graph and "rosrun tf view_frames"? Are there any warnings or errors in rqt_console?

**Comment by [gokhan.acer](https://answers.ros.org/users/41387/gokhan.acer/) on 2019-07-09**:
Did you solved this problem? I'm also getting this error, and I couldn't create map turtlebot3+gazebo+nav2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I probably faced the same problem (TurtleBot + Gazebo + nav2d) and this solved it:

```
<param name="/laser_frame" value="base_footprint" />
```

Just add this line to your modified tutorial3.launch file. Mapper should be able to process the scan data now.

---

Originally posted by [Caesarion](https://answers.ros.org/users/31627/caesarion/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gokhan.acer](https://answers.ros.org/users/41387/gokhan.acer/) on 2019-07-09**:
Your solution doen not work me. I still have same issue .

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2019-07-12**:
Setting the laser_frame to base_footprint doesn't seem right to me. It should be the frame where your laser device (the origin of the generated scans) sits on your robot.